# How to create a custom blured shape with rounded corners in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, clip, flutter-layout

I want to draw a custom shape similar to the marked area of below image. Is there a way to clip this custom shape with blur effect and then specify the radius for the corners?

[image: This marked shaped]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is the
[full example](https://gist.github.com/rahichesoft/8b240ce5ccc83c3060f5134cacdaf33c)

[image]

```
class Customclipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 20);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0.0, size.height, 20.0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width - 20.0, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height, size.width, size.height - 20);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 50.0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 30.0, size.width - 20.0, 30.0);
    path.lineTo(20.0, 5.0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

1. Created all the rounded corners using **quadraticBezierTo**
2. Created a Container inside a ClipPath
3. Used the Colors.white70 for the container color

Comment: how can i create a circular diamond shape ???
i created the diamond shape , but i could not add circular radius.

Answer (score 1):

I use this library, which helps to build shapes from `svg` files:
https://fluttershapemaker.com/

All you need to do is, export your shape as `svg` and paste it there